Canon EOS 1N HS (film) camera remote control port
What type of remote control plug has the Canon 1N HS?
It's an analog film camera manufactured 1994-ish, and I have a hard time identifying the type of RC plug, it doesn't look like any modern RC port you can find for example on the one-digit digital EOS.
Just for context, I'm looking for buying either only the plug, as I want to build/adapt my own DIY remote control, or buy cheap replacement RCs and cut off the cable, however besides some expensive original Canon RCs for the 1N I haven't found anything yet.

I don't really understand your question. I looked at the manual for the camera, and it seems that the remote needed is called something like 60T3. They seem to be cheaply available to buy online. But maybe I've missed your point.

It's a proprietary "T3" plug.
You need either a 60-T3 release or a T3 adapter (converts a mechanical release to electrical).
